# how to pass object array to useEffect dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am storing an object array in mobx store.

```
// type.ts
export interface TabsType {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

// store.ts
class EngineGroupStore {
  tabArray: TabsType[] = [];

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      tabArray: observable,
      setTabArray: action,
    });
  }

  setTabArray(tabs: TabsType[]) {
    this.tabArray = tabs;
  }
}

export default new EngineGroupStore();
```

I passed `TabsArray` to the dependency array of `useEffect`.
Because useEffect does not allow deep comparison of arrays, I used `useDeepCompareEffect` of `use-deep-compare-effect`.

```
 useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [engineGroupStore.tabArray]);
```

when a specific event occurs, the array object is initialized with [], but rendering is not performed.

```
 const change = async () => {
   EngineGroupStore.setTabArray([]);
 };
```

I confirmed that the object array stored in the store is initialized (length is 0). However, the `useDeepCompareEffect` function is not called. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like engineGroupStore.tabArray does not change, am not sure why you would need to use useDeepCompareEffect, just descructure tabArray and have that as an argument?

Avoid classes wherever you can - use es6 arrow if you can.

setTabArray is not using a useState hook so there is no change in state and thus no re-render.